# 2 different random number from 4 different range Python

Tags: python-3.x, random

I want 2 different random numbers from 4 different ranges. There are solutions about that, but I want each selected random numbers will be from different ranges. Like from 4 ranges given, if first random number is chosen from 2nd range given, then other random number will be chosen from other 3 ranges given rather than the 2nd range. Any help please ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use `random.sample` to select x different items from a list.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample

Now, given your four ranges, you want to first select two different ranges from it, then from each range select a number.

```
chosen_ranges = random.sample(input_range_list, 2)
chosen_numbers = [random.sample(range) for range in chosen_ranges]
```